# Why is IIS 8.0 Express using the old project names after rename in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, project, iis-express

After some naming confusing my team decided to rename some projects and the namespaces for all the existing code files in the project. (In Visual Studio 2012)

We've changed:

- the Project Names
- the  Assembly Name, Default namespace, Title and Product entries in the Project Properties
- the namespaces for each code file in each project that was renamed
- all the using statements for the revised namespaces
- cleared out the old .dll files in the /bin directory (for the routing engine to not find multiple controllers)
- the actual folders themselves, requiring removing and re-adding the projects to the solution (and re-doing references to the projects that were renamed)

After all of this, **IIS 8.0 Express** still insists on using the old project names for the site names (while locally debugging). How can I fix this?

**Edit:**
The real question is this: *How does IIS 8.0 Express determine the site name*?

Here's a snipped from (one of) the .csproj files for a website

```
<ProjectExtensions>
  <VisualStudio>
    <FlavorProperties GUID="{349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21}">
      <WebProjectProperties>
        <UseIIS>True</UseIIS>
        <AutoAssignPort>True</AutoAssignPort>
        <DevelopmentServerPort>52143</DevelopmentServerPort>
        <DevelopmentServerVPath>/</DevelopmentServerVPath>
        <IISUrl>http://localhost:53177/</IISUrl>
        <NTLMAuthentication>False</NTLMAuthentication>
        <UseCustomServer>False</UseCustomServer>
        <CustomServerUrl>
        </CustomServerUrl>
        <SaveServerSettingsInUserFile>False</SaveServerSettingsInUserFile>
      </WebProjectProperties>
    </FlavorProperties>
  </VisualStudio>
</ProjectExtensions>
```

...and nothing for site name.

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles if you want to know why I changed your title.

Comment: Thanks for that, both the change and the link.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem isn't in the Project at all.

In the applicationhost.config file [(iis.net link)](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.applicationhost/sites/site), typically in

`(user-dir)\My Documents\IISExpress\config\applicationhost.config`

There are settings for the a site. Simply change the name attribute of the site.

```
       <site name="MvcApplication1" id="3">
            <application path="/" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
                <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="(whateverpath)\My Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\MvcApplication1\MvcApplication1" />
            </application>
            <bindings>
                <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:57733:localhost" />
            </bindings>
        </site>
```

Comment: In addition to what [Christopher Stevenson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/612512/christopher-stevenson) said, I also had an additional `<location>` entry in **applicationhost.config** that I had to remove. For some reason, the steps I took in renaming had left the old entry with the old name _and_ added a new one. I recommend searching in that file for any other instances of the old project name.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to find and change these names in csproj files and sln files as well (which are basically xml files with file extensions that VS uses).

First and most importantly, back up all your stuff, just in case. Next, do a text search for the old names (hopefully they weren't called something like "if") within the csproj/sln files. Change the names, and then try launching.

I'm not aware of a tool or an automated way of doing this, but I have successfully done this by hand as described above.

Comment: The old name occurrences were excised by the above steps: no text string of the original namespace and/or project name exists in the relevant .csproj and .sln files. (I just checked with Notepad++)

Answer (score 0):

Did you reconfigure IIS Express?  On the project propertis, on the web tab, click "Create Virtual Directory"

Comment: Unfortunately, clicking on Create Virtual Directory wasn't enough to change the name IIS is displaying for the website

Comment: You may have to delete the virtual directory from IIS Express, then recreate it.  Go into applicationhost.config in your My Documents\IIS Express folder and delete the entries for it.  Remember to shutdown IIS Express.