# How to rename an IIS Express website in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, iis, webmatrix-2

I initially created a site in Webmatrix 2. I just called it website1. I've now been working on the site in Visual Studio 2012 and I would like to rename it. It doesn't appear you can rename it directly, but in the .sln file there is a project entry which contains the string "website1". I renamed it and re-started VS. The new name briefly displays but then gets overwritten with the original name. So now I have the .sln file with the new name and nowhere within the folders does it reference the old name - i've searched every file. But yet VS insists on calling the site website1. So i'm totally confused.

Any ideas where VS stores the name of websites? The only thing I can come up with is how VS integrates with IIS Express. Perhaps it is taking the name from IIS instead?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is IIS 8.0 Express using the old project names after rename in Visual Studio 2012](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12359995/why-is-iis-8-0-express-using-the-old-project-names-after-rename-in-visual-studio)

Comment: use C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express>appcmd.exe to manage the web apps e.g. *appcmd.exe list vdir* https://gyorgybalassy.wordpress.com/2013/12/02/cleaning-up-iis-express-configuration/

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I had the exact same problem, and after a lot of hair pulling realized that IIS Express (as you said) somehow was the culprit. However, I couldn't find out where the site name was stored.

This is what I ended up doing (in addition to renaming directories and replacing the old project name with the new one in the solution file):

- Open up the `.sln` file
- Locate the `Project` entry for the web site you want to rename
- Change the port of the URL. This will force IIS Express to treat it as a new site.

Hope this helps someone!

Comment: Using some of your information, I found that IISExpress had an "applicationhost.config" file located in my %UserProfile%\Documents\IISExpress\config directory.  Opening that file showed all the sites.  In my case it already had the name of the site in it that I wanted in my solution, so the solution kept adding a (1) to the end of the website.  Changed the name in there and removed the dup, restarted the solution and it worked fine.

Comment: Thanks god i found the solution here, i just experience this problem. VS2013 keep add 1 to my website name.

Comment: Yea, thanks for this. The comment above about the %USERPROFILE%\Documents\IISExpress\config\applicationhost.config was the lead I needed.

Answer (score 32):

I just encounter the same problem with you during using VS 2013, it turned out that it's caused by IIS Express, finally I solved it by following steps:

1. Find the applicationhost.cofig of your IIS Express, usually it should be listed in Folder *C:\Users{username}\Documents\IISExpress\config*
2. Locate the corresponding *site* section of your project in the cofig file
3. Remove all those site section with simillar site name like *ProjectNameABC* and *ProjectNameABC(1)*
4. Close and Reopen your solution in vs, you'll found that the spefic name for your web project come back

Comment: This Solution Work for me ! (y)

Comment: Instead of closing and reopening the solution I had to click Create Virtual Directory button under the project properties/Web in VS.

Comment: Can someone tell me how do you do it in visual studio 2019?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem for **HTTPS** and **Visual Studio 2015**.

The IIS Express configuration file "C:\Users{username}\Documents\IISExpress\config\applicationhost.config" **didn´t have** the reference for my site.

I found the reference **inside the solution** directory in a hide directory

**"{Solution}\.vs\config\applicationhost.config"**

I removed the entry for the old copy site, closed and reopen the project and everything was right.