# Change site name in applicationhost.config

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I copied one of my friend's MVC WebAPI application and using the same for my purpose.
When I run the application, I see his company name as `Site Name` when IIS Express starts in tray(taskbar bottom right corner).

I have removed his company name from entire application. All project files, etc. But still I see the company name when the application runs.
so I checked in the `applicationhost.config` file in `.vs` folder. There I could see the company name under Sites tag.

```
<sites>
<site name="GoaPeeep.WebAPI" id="2">
                <application path="/" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
                    <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\Projects\WnSFramework\WebAPI\WebAPI" />
                </application>
                <bindings>
                    <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:61843:localhost" />
                </bindings>
            </site>
</sites>
```

If I remove/change `GoaPeep` to anything else, my application does not run. It says, **"Process with ID #### is not running."**

I would like to know, how this `site name` is related with the application. Now that I have removed GoaPeep from everywhere in application, where it is referring to?
How can I change this site name now?

Comment: Got the answer from https://stackoverflow.com/a/16187554/3781734

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason you see your friend's website name is that the project has the same name in the IDE.

Meaning if you can rename the project, or make a new one with your intended name and copy only the functional code, then it should display what you want in the system tray/taskbar.